# Importance of command line to Python 2

Tags: python, command-line, python-2.x

Learn Python the Hard Way puts great emphasis on familiarity with command line. Into ex15 and haven't yet been called on to do much with it. He seems to suggest that I'll eventually hit a wall if I don't complete his command line crash course. Wondering just how vital it is.

Comment: You're not too old to learn, man! Just keep your chin up and the fingers on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is more opinion-based, but most of the time I've worked with python I used an IDE and did not touch the command line until a hack-a-thon when we were uploading the code to bitbucket regularly. The good part of using command-line rather than a "heavy-weight" IDE is the easiness with which you can specify parameters on a "program-by-program" basis. Is this what you were looking for when you asked your question?

Also, when working with others, the command line help you avoid distractions such as the inevitable conversation where we each defend our favorite IDEs :)